# Make word in into a link jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, appendto

I'm trying to make this:

```
<td class="Monthly Status-cell">/fileid=XXXX</td>
```

Display as

http://www.domain.com/fileid=XXXX

Can you tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
$('.Status-cell').replaceWith(function() {
var url = $.trim($(this).text());
return '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">' + url + '</a>';
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: `replaceWith` replaces the matching elements - in this case your `td`

Comment: Your'e **replacing** a `td` with an `a`.  Presumably, this `td` is within a `tr`.  `a` is not a valid child of a `tr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of `.replaceWith()`. While using `replaceWith` you are replacing the `td` with anchor inside your table, which is invalid and that must be causing your alignment to get messed up.

```
$('.Status-cell').html(function(_, currentText) {
   var url = "http://www.domain.com" + $.trim(currentText);
   return '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">' + url + '</a>';
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RNBL8/)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than replace the `td` with a link you should place the link in the `td`. Also you didn't add the domain to the link

```
$('.Status-cell').html(function() {
    var url = window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host+$.trim($(this).text());
    return '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">' + url + '</a>';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bUpYE/1/

Answer (score 0):

Place the link in the cell using `.html()` instead of `.replaceWith()`:

```
var domain = window.location.hostname; // current domain
$('.Status-cell').html(function(i, value) {
    var link = domain + $.trim(value);
    return '<a href="//' + link + '">' + link + '</a>';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/ZUYCX/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.Status-cell').html(function(idx, value){
    value = $.trim(value);
    return '<a href="http://www.domain.com' + value + '">http://www.domain.com' + value + '</a>';
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xtbyP/)

Comment: I'm sure it's minor, but calling `trim` twice isn't ideal.